# Автозаполнение из Safari в UIWebView

Tags: ios, xcode, auth, safari

Прошу уточнить или подсказать решение, если таковое имеется.

Ситуация следующая: В приложении есть возможность авторизоваться через соцсети FB, TW. Если не авторизован аккаунт на телефоне, то показываем UIWebView cо страницей авторизации, но приходится логин/пароль снова вбивать, в отличие от варианта с safari, когда пользователь уже залогинен на странице facebook в safari.

Вопрос в том, имеется ли возможность использовать автозаполнение логина/пароля из keychain Safari в моём UIWebView?

Как вариант можно перекидывать пользователя в safari, потом обратно. Но Apple каждый второй раз реджектит обновление приложения по этому поводу. 
Поэтому я хочу уйти от этой реализации.

> 10.6 Details
>
> We noticed an issue in your app that contributes to a lower quality
>   user experience than Apple users expect. Specifically,
>
> - Upon tapping social networks buttons in the app, a web page in mobile Safari opens for logging in, then returns the user to the app.
>     The user should be able to log in without opening Safari first.

В Apple написано:

> The iOS gives an application access to only its own keychain items.

Comment: Посмотрите это. Думаю, что не сложно будет разобраться
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086470/how-do-i-autofill-username-and-password-in-uiwebview-ios-app

Answer (score 1):

То, что вы пытаетесь сделать на iOS реализовать нельзя. Каждое приложение имеет свой сэндбокс и не имеет доступа куда либо еще (к данным другого приложения или мобильного Сафари).

В то же время, если вы у себя в UIWebView сохраните какие то cookies, к ним вы имеете доступ в последующих сессиях.

Мне кажется то, что вы пытаетесь сделать можно реализовать через Facebook iOS SDK.